# If Else does not change gridviews to visible on selectindexchanged c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

It's quite simple, when a user selects a row, it should bring up related rows from either of the two tables, either in Panel1 or Panel2. My problem is that when I select a row where only one table have content for, it works fine, reveals the table and its associated Maintenance_ID, I go to select another row where both tables have the associated Maintenance_ID and it only reveals the content for the table that was already previously revealed.

When I put a breakpoint I notice that the Rows.Count for the other table equates to 0, but when I run the program over and select a row where both tables have content, it reveals both tables as it should. And when I go to select another row with content from only one table it still reveals both tables, only it displays the table that doesn't have a related Maintenance_ID as empty.

So obviously I'm doing something wrong syntactically but I'm not sure what, open to suggestions.

EDIT: Here are my data bound events and new SelectedIndexChanged code but now nothing actually happens:

```
protected void MaintenanceTable_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow r = MaintenanceTable.Rows[MaintenanceTable.SelectedIndex];
        string mid = r.Cells[2].Text;
 lpDataSource.SelectParameters["mid"].DefaultValue = mid;
        lpDataSource.DataBind();
        wsDataSource.SelectParameters["mid"].DefaultValue = mid;
        wsDataSource.DataBind();
}
protected void lpTable_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (lpTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lpTableLabel.Visible = true;
            Panel1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            lpTableLabel.Visible = false;
            Panel1.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            wsTableLabel.Visible = true;
            Panel2.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            wsTableLabel.Visible = false;
            Panel2.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Associated GridViews and DataSources:

```
<asp:GridView ID="MaintenanceTable" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Maintenance_ID" DataSourceID="MaintDataSource" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" Width="1000px" OnRowDeleted="MaintenanceTable_RowDeleted" OnSelectedIndexChanged="MaintenanceTable_SelectedIndexChanged" ShowFooter="True">


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MaintDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:itassetmgmtConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Maintenance]" >


<asp:GridView ID="lpTable" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="lpDataSource" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" DataKeyNames="Laptop_ID" Height="39px" Width="1427px" OnDataBound="lpTable_DataBound" >


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="lpDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:itassetmgmtConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Laptops] WHERE [Maintenance_ID]=@mid" ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues">


<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="wsDataSource" EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical" DataKeyNames="Workstation_ID" Height="39px" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound" >


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="wsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:itassetmgmtConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Workstations] WHERE [Maintenance_ID]=@mid"  ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues">
```

Comment: What is GridView1?  Your first if statement is dependent on lpTable.  It makes me wanna guess that there's a wsTable that you're second if statement should be dependent on.

Comment: I didn't bother changing the ID for the second table. GridView1 is my Workstations table, LP stands for Laptops for my lpTable

Comment: Should you clear lpTable and GridView1 before executing the queries and data binding? Also, since this is an indexChanged event, shouldn't account for -1 (when a row is not selected)?

Comment: Problem still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this wrong.  Your query strings do not change except for the selected field based on the selected row.  This tells me several things:

1. The field associated with this code: `r.Cells[2].Text` should be a DataKey of `MaintenanceTable`
2. Each of your other tables (lp, ws) has their own DataSource as you are setting the `Select` and forcing a `Databind()` but are not assigning a datasource, which leads me to believe you have set their `DataSourceID` (as you should)
3. The Databind event on the dependent tables is not happening due to your playing with the visibility of the parent controls.  This is because of the order of things in the [**Page Lifecycle**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx#lifecycle_events).  When you set the visibility of controls to false in the `MaintenanceTable_SelectedIndexChanged` event, The `Panel`s and their relevant child control's `Databind` events are never raised.  which is why your visibility issues are always a step behind.

so what should you do:

1. Comment out your existing code above.
2. Add the field associated with `r.Cells[2].Text` as a DataKey of `MaintenanceTable`
3. Add the select statement to each of the dependent DataSources but modified
   to accept a parameter rather than appending the parameter as a string.
4. Add a ControlParameter to each of the dependant Tables DataSources that references the SelectedValue of `MaintenanceTable`
5. Panel Visibility needs to be set AFTER the Databind happens so do this in the `Page_PreRenderComplete` event or even better, in the `DataBound` events of the respective dependent tables.

Edit: Generally speaking you were trying to control too much too soon in the SelectedIndexChanged event.  Typically I prefer to set state variable during events via Class member variables if they only need to exist for a given lifecycle or in ViewState or Session if they need to be persisted.  Then let controls sort themselves by accessing those state variables in their own respective events where necessary.

**ADDENDUM**

This is all that is needed to generate a webpage that fills dependent tables based on a row selection from a Main Table.  Absolutely no Code behind Required.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMaintenanceTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="case_id">
  <Columns>
    <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="caption" HeaderText="caption" SortExpression="caption"></asp:BoundField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:SomeConnectionString %>'
    SelectCommand="SELECT top 10 caption, case_id FROM tbl_case_info">
</asp:SqlDataSource>



<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
  <asp:GridView ID="lpTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      DataSourceID="lpDataSource"
      DataKeyNames="invoice_id">
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="invoice_number" HeaderText="invoice_number" SortExpression="invoice_number"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>

  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="lpDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:SomeConnectionString %>'
    SelectCommand="SELECT invoice_number, invoice_id FROM tbl_invoice WHERE (case_id = @CaseID)">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="CaseID" 
                            ControlID="gvMaintenanceTable"
                            PropertyName="SelectedValue"></asp:ControlParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>



<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
  <asp:GridView ID="wsTable" runat="server" DataSourceID="wsDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="caption" HeaderText="caption" SortExpression="caption"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>

  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="wsDataSource" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:SomeConnectionString %>'
    SelectCommand="SELECT caption, user_id, case_id FROM tbl_case_info WHERE (case_id = @CaseID)">
    <SelectParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="CaseID"
                            ControlID="gvMaintenanceTable" 
                            PropertyName="SelectedValue"></asp:ControlParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
  </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>
```

And this is the Code Behind for visibility (pardon the VB) assuming that the labels appear inside the Panels.  Consider using the Gridview `Caption` property instead of an `<asp:Label>` if the label is associated with the table

```
 Private Sub lpTable_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lpTable.DataBound
     Panel1.Visible = (lpTable.Rows.Count > 0)
 End Sub

 Private Sub wsTable_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles wsTable.DataBound
     Panel2.Visible = (wsTable.Rows.Count > 0)
 End Sub
```

EDIT:  Make sure the `Panel`s reset their `Visibility` property to `True` otherwise, once false, their contained `Gridview`s will never `Databind` on subsequent row selections of the main table.

```
Private Sub Panel1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel1.Load
    Panel1.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Panel2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Panel2.Load
    Panel2.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: can you post the markup for the 3 gridviews ( just the main tag) and the associated datasources?

Comment: if not i'll try to post an example of what I believe you are trying to accomplish

Comment: So tried this:`<SelectParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter Name="mid" ControlID="MaintenanceTable" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
                        </SelectParameters>`
in the two data sources and this `Panel1.Visible = (lpTable.Rows.Count > 0);` in the two data bound events, still no go

Comment: First make sure that the DataKeyName `Maintenance_ID` is not null. that will cause the dependant datasources to fail (unless `CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False"`) Also, change the references from `mid` and `@mid` to something less "reserved-word-like" like `maint_id` and `@maint_id`  And double check that the Panels default to Visible and If that doesn't do it run the code thru the debugger with breakpoints at the databind events and see they're getting hit.

Comment: it's the end of my day here for today.  If you have not figured it out overnight I'll be happy to continue helping in the morning

Comment: Thank you so much, it's the end of my day here as well, I'll debug and put my breakpoint in the morning and check it out.

Comment: So after applying my breakpoints I found out that the program doesn't even get to the databound events, so I put data binding events on the data source and it brought me back to my original issue.

Comment: did you verify everything else before running it through the debugger?

Comment: I fell victim to my own advice.  Make sure you set the panels Visibility to True in their load events.   Once they're false the databinds for the child tables on subsequent row selections never happen.  Apologies. I'll update my answer

Comment: Perfect! Looks like that was the trick! Thank you thank you thank you